# Handle deny all in testing web interface through Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have a controller with the following access rules:

```
array('deny',  // deny all users
    'users'=>array('*'),
),
```

I want to test that code (every user authorized or not can't access to this controller via the web) and have the following:

```
public function testShow()
{
  $this->open('?r=link');
}
```

But I get the following error in my console:

> 1) LinkTest::testShow
>   PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Response from Selenium RC server for testComplete().
>   XHR ERROR: URL = http://127.0.0.1/url/index-test.php/?r=link Response_Code = 403 Error_Message = >
>   CHttpException.

I want to make a test where I can ensure that link controller not visible via web.

Answer (score 0):

Well the 403 response is a permission denied error. So it seems as though it's working correctly. Perhaps you just need to configure Selenium. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730385/selenium-dont-stop-on-http-error-403) for some help.